# Get data from http request in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

When I use `response.on('data' callback)` I get the data as soon as it is received. This results in the data getting passed part by part. 

I wish to get the data all together and call the `parser.parseString(chunk,parseData)`. How do I achieve this?

The following is my code.

```
var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ', chunk);

    //parser.parseString(chunk,parseData);       
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log('The end');
    });

});

request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

request.write(str);    
request.end();
}
```

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data

Answer (score 2):

You should create variable, where you'll be writing document data

```
var document;
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    document += chunk;
}
```

Then you should trigger your parser at end of document

```
response.on('end', function() {
    parser.parseString(document, parseData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider or are using the Express framework, see if the body-parser middleware meets your need (c.f. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)